# MySQL select date BETWEEN syntax prints wrong results

Tags: mysql, date, between

I have this long and nasty `MySQL` query:

```
SELECT * FROM
    studentdates sd
        INNER JOIN
    students s ON s.student_id = sd.student_id
        INNER JOIN
    cityselections cs ON cs.city_id = s.student_city_id
        INNER JOIN
    customers c ON c.customer_id = s.student_customer_id
        INNER JOIN
    price_to_course_number ptcn ON ptcn.ptcn_course_number = sd.student_course_number
        INNER JOIN
    pricegroups pg ON pg.price_id = ptcn.ptcn_price_id
WHERE
    ('2012-10-01' OR '2012-10-31' BETWEEN sd.student_startdate AND sd.student_enddate)
        AND cs.city_id = '12'
        AND sd.student_course_number = '46248'
ORDER BY s.student_lastname ASC
```

This will print the following lines (edited out unnecessary columns):

```
+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| student_id | student_startdate  | student_enddate |
+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| 299        | 2012-09-24         | 2012-10-21      |
| 299        | 2012-09-17         | 2012-09-23      |
+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Notice in my query I have `WHERE ('2012-10-01' OR '2012-10-31' BETWEEN sd.student_startdate AND sd.student_enddate)`

Why do I get this as a result?

`| 299        | 2012-09-17         | 2012-09-23      |`

Comment: Does it work if you do 2 between. 1 for 2012-10-01 and 1 for 2012-10-31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` and `OR` are used to connect Boolean expressions. In your case, you have the following expression:

```
'2012-10-01' OR '2012-10-31' BETWEEN sd.student_startdate AND sd.student_enddate
```

This has two parts (joined by an OR relationship):

1. `'2012-10-01'`
2. `'2012-10-31' BETWEEN sd.student_startdate AND sd.student_enddate`

The first part will always evaluate to `true` (it is non-zero, non-null), therefore the result of this expression will also always be true.

---

Did you perhaps mean this instead?

```
sd.student_enddate >= '2012-10-01' AND sd.student_startdate <= '2012-10-31'
```

Comment: Thank's alot for giving me a detailed explanation. It work's like a charm now.

Comment: @ls-whats the difference between urs query and mine below.?

Comment: @AnandPhadke It looks like you have the start and end columns swapped. Your query will return rows contained within October, whereas this one will return rows which have any part of the date period in October. Since it looked like the OP wanted to keep the row with dates 9/24-10/21, I assumed this was the one he was looking for and was apparently correct.

Comment: OP needs data between '2012-10-01' and '2012-10-31' rite?

Comment: @AnandPhadke It would appear the OP needs data *crossing into* October 2012.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
    studentdates sd
        INNER JOIN
    students s ON s.student_id = sd.student_id
        INNER JOIN
    cityselections cs ON cs.city_id = s.student_city_id
        INNER JOIN
    customers c ON c.customer_id = s.student_customer_id
        INNER JOIN
    price_to_course_number ptcn ON ptcn.ptcn_course_number = sd.student_course_number
        INNER JOIN
    pricegroups pg ON pg.price_id = ptcn.ptcn_price_id
WHERE
    sd.student_startdate >='2012-10-01' and  sd.student_enddate <='2012-10-31' 
        AND cs.city_id = '12'
        AND sd.student_course_number = '46248'
ORDER BY s.student_lastname ASC
```

Comment: Then I guess there is no data for the specific values in where clause